# LIWC2015 import in r

Tags: r, dictionary

I use LIWC2015 as student.

I would like to use it with R.

I found the [package](https://github.com/kbenoit/LIWCalike) `LIWCalike` with which it is possible to use LIWC dictonary.

I have installed the dictionary to my computer.

However I can't find with file I should include into my path in order to use it with. There is the executable version, also a jar file and I extracted dictonaries however they are only available into pdf format.

What file should I use from LIWC2015 dictonary in order to use it in R?

This example code is from package but I don't have a cat file

```
liwc2007dict <- dictionary(file = "~/Dropbox/QUANTESS/dictionaries/LIWC/LIWC2007.cat", 
                           format = "wordstat")
tail(liwc2007dict, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the format of the file in the code in R.

Try this:

```
liwc2015dict <- dictionary(file = "~/Dropbox/QUANTESS/dictionaries/LIWC/LIWC2015_English_Flat.dic",
                            format = "LIWC")
```

It's documented [here](https://github.com/kbenoit/LIWCalike/blob/master/R/liwcalike.R).